# Lost administrator password on Windows Server 2012 (with RDP)

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp, password-reset

Somehow I've lost my administrator password for a hosted Windows Server 2012 instance. I have access to the server using the Remote Desktop Connection and Plesk.

I can boot the server in recovery mode and then have access to "my" booting drive. I already tried the trick to copy `cmd.exe` over `Utilman.exe`, but after rebooting the server in normal mode I still can't access it.

The problem is that I don't even come to the logon screen of Windows Server 2012 with the Remote Desktop Connection. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to modify the RDP configuration so that it does not ask for credentials before connecting:

http://chall32.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/fixing-remote-desktop-annoyances.html